# Slow SQL Querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have a script that includes 3 inner joins. It seems that when I add the 3rd inner join, the script runs extremely slow. The first 2 tables have around 3-4 thousand rows, the 3rd has 633 thousand rows, and the last table has only 36 rows. I've attempted indexing, but I don't notice a change. I'm including my script before and after indexing. It takes around 12 minutes to return only the top 5 entries. If there's more information needed, please ask. I'm new to database management.

BEFORE INDEXING:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 sn.NAME, cd.ASSIGNEDPOLICY, cd.COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER, ad.COVERAGECODE, co."DESCRIPTION"
From SNAMES sn
inner join TCUSDTL cd on sn.NAMEID = cd.NAMEID 
inner join TPOLACTD ad on sn.NAMEID = ad.NAMEID 
inner join SCOVTBL co on ad.COVERAGECODE = co.COVERAGE
ORDER BY NAME
```

AFTER INDEXING:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 sn.NAME, cd.ASSIGNEDPOLICY, cd.COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER, ad.COVERAGECODE, co."DESCRIPTION"
From SNAMES sn WITH(INDEX(SNAMES_names))
inner join TCUSDTL cd WITH(INDEX(TCUSDTL_policies)) on sn.NAMEID = cd.NAMEID 
inner join TPOLACTD ad WITH(INDEX(TPOLACTD_coverage)) on sn.NAMEID = ad.NAMEID 
inner join SCOVTBL co WITH(INDEX(SCOVTBL_coverage)) on ad.COVERAGECODE = co.COVERAGE
ORDER BY NAME
```

EXECUTION PLAN:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.5" Build="13.0.703.859" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="1000" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" CardinalityEstimationModelVersion="120" StatementSubTreeCost="5270.92" StatementText="SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 sn.NAME, cd.ASSIGNEDPOLICY, cd.COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER, bd.COVERAGECODE, sd.&quot;DESCRIPTION&quot;&#xD;&#xA;FROM SNAMES sn&#xD;&#xA;inner join TCUSDTL cd on sn.NAMEID = cd.NAMEID &#xD;&#xA;inner join TPOLACTD bd on sn.NAMEID = bd.NAMEID &#xD;&#xA;inner join SCOVTBL sd on bd.COVERAGECODE = sd.COVERAGE&#xD;&#xA;ORDER BY NAME" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x5C4838D1FC1E530E" QueryPlanHash="0x854BE2475051DE74" RetrievedFromCache="true" SecurityPolicyApplied="false">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan NonParallelPlanReason="EstimatedDOPIsOne" CachedPlanSize="104" CompileTime="27" CompileCPU="26" CompileMemory="1144">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="3584" SerialDesiredMemory="7383960" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="11744005" EstimatedPagesCached="734000" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="1" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="94" EstimateCPU="0.0001" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1000" LogicalOp="Top" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Top" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="5270.92">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAME" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="ASSIGNEDPOLICY" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
              </OutputList>
              <Top RowCount="false" IsPercent="false" WithTies="false">
                <TopExpression>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="(1000)">
                    <Const ConstValue="(1000)" />
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </TopExpression>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="94" EstimateCPU="5177.31" EstimateIO="0.0112613" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1000" LogicalOp="Distinct Sort" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sort" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="5270.92">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAME" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="ASSIGNEDPOLICY" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <MemoryFractions Input="0.985219" Output="1" />
                  <Sort Distinct="true">
                    <OrderBy>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAME" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="ASSIGNEDPOLICY" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                      <OrderByColumn Ascending="true">
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
                      </OrderByColumn>
                    </OrderBy>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="94" EstimateCPU="75.5786" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="44400500" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="93.6068">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAME" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="ASSIGNEDPOLICY" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <MemoryFractions Input="0.816955" Output="0.0120753" />
                      <Hash>
                        <DefinedValues />
                        <HashKeysBuild>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                        </HashKeysBuild>
                        <HashKeysProbe>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                        </HashKeysProbe>
                        <ProbeResidual>
                          <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DC02001].[dbo].[TCUSDTL].[NAMEID] as [cd].[NAMEID]=[DC02001].[dbo].[TPOLACTD].[NAMEID] as [bd].[NAMEID]">
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </ProbeResidual>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="33" EstimateCPU="0.283312" EstimateIO="2.24609" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="257414" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="2.5294" TableCardinality="257414">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="ASSIGNEDPOLICY" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="ASSIGNEDPOLICY" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" Column="COMPANYPOLICYNUMBER" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <Object Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TCUSDTL]" Alias="[cd]" IndexKind="Heap" Storage="RowStore" />
                          </TableScan>
                        </RelOp>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="86" EstimateCPU="7.96164" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1405060" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="15.4988">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAME" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <MemoryFractions Input="0.179818" Output="0.00265786" />
                          <Hash>
                            <DefinedValues />
                            <HashKeysBuild>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAMEID" />
                            </HashKeysBuild>
                            <HashKeysProbe>
                              <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                            </HashKeysProbe>
                            <ProbeResidual>
                              <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DC02001].[dbo].[SNAMES].[NAMEID] as [sn].[NAMEID]=[DC02001].[dbo].[TPOLACTD].[NAMEID] as [bd].[NAMEID]">
                                <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Compare>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </ProbeResidual>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="56" EstimateCPU="0.0416996" EstimateIO="0.221644" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="37766" LogicalOp="Index Scan" NodeId="5" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.263343" TableCardinality="37766">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAME" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                <DefinedValues>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                  <DefinedValue>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Alias="[sn]" Column="NAME" />
                                  </DefinedValue>
                                </DefinedValues>
                                <Object Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SNAMES]" Index="[SNAMES_names]" Alias="[sn]" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                              </IndexScan>
                            </RelOp>
                            <RelOp AvgRowSize="46" EstimateCPU="4.94636" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="702122" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="6" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="7.27381">
                              <OutputList>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                                <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
                              </OutputList>
                              <MemoryFractions Input="0.00322675" Output="4.7694E-05" />
                              <Hash>
                                <DefinedValues />
                                <HashKeysBuild>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="COVERAGE" />
                                </HashKeysBuild>
                                <HashKeysProbe>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                                </HashKeysProbe>
                                <ProbeResidual>
                                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[DC02001].[dbo].[SCOVTBL].[COVERAGE] as [sd].[COVERAGE]=[DC02001].[dbo].[TPOLACTD].[COVERAGECODE] as [bd].[COVERAGECODE]">
                                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="COVERAGE" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </ProbeResidual>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="37" EstimateCPU="0.0001966" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="36" LogicalOp="Index Scan" NodeId="7" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0033216" TableCardinality="36">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="COVERAGE" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                    <DefinedValues>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="COVERAGE" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Alias="[sd]" Column="DESCRIPTION" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                    </DefinedValues>
                                    <Object Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[SCOVTBL]" Index="[SCOVTBL_coverage]" Alias="[sd]" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                                  </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                                <RelOp AvgRowSize="21" EstimateCPU="0.6973" EstimateIO="1.62683" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="633766" LogicalOp="Index Scan" NodeId="8" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="2.32413" TableCardinality="633766">
                                  <OutputList>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                                  </OutputList>
                                  <IndexScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                                    <DefinedValues>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="NAMEID" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                      <DefinedValue>
                                        <ColumnReference Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Alias="[bd]" Column="COVERAGECODE" />
                                      </DefinedValue>
                                    </DefinedValues>
                                    <Object Database="[DC02001]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[TPOLACTD]" Index="[TPOLACTD_coverage]" Alias="[bd]" IndexKind="NonClustered" Storage="RowStore" />
                                  </IndexScan>
                                </RelOp>
                              </Hash>
                            </RelOp>
                          </Hash>
                        </RelOp>
                      </Hash>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Sort>
                </RelOp>
              </Top>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: Profile the query (using the tools available for whatever database you're using, since there seems to be some confusion coming from you on that) to examine the actual execution plan.  When there's a performance problem, measuring and identifying the bottlenecks is always the first step.

Comment: The "TOP" keyword is in MS-SqlServer, not MySQL.  Using SQL Query Analyzer you can "Debug query performance problems. (Show Execution Plan, Show Server Trace, Show Client Statistics, Index Tuning Wizard)" - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216945(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: My mistake. I quickly typed MySQL without thinking. I'm using MS-SQLServer. Also, why the negative vote? Learning isn't a bad thing. I will take a look into the tools you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Consider including your execution plan in your question. We may then be able to give you some guidance as to the cause.

Comment: The distinct sorting seems to the the bottle neck, as it has a cost of 97%. I'm not really sure how to go about changing that though.

Comment: Couple things.  One, do not use index query hints, ever, unless as an absolute last resort.  Use the same query before and after creating indexes.  Two, as others have mentioned, show the execution plan in your question and post the indexes you have created.

Comment: Unless your testing has vetted a need to use index hints it is best to avoid them. You don't want to force an index to be used. when you use hints like that you are saying you know more about to utilize the indexes than the sql engine. It is very rare when an index hint needs to be used. The best way you can let us help you here is to post the actual execution plan. The ddl (including index definitions) would help too.

Comment: I suspect that the basic query approach is sub-optimal. Keep in mind TOP x is post process - it must do all of the work before returning only the first 5 rows.   Your JOIN is not narrow enough for what you are looking for. Remember - you are dumping *all* rows from these tables - so an index is unlikely to help, and will take awhile.  Is there a Cluster index on these tables?   If DISTINCT is your bottleneck then it is spending time in SORT and removing duplicates - which you must have lots of.   I would rethink this query and possibly you can't do it via INNER JOIN alone.

Comment: I'll add to my previous - is there anything else to add to the WHERE clause?  I see Top 5 - why?.  How many rows output from this query without TOP?  Do you really want all 650,000 rows? Can it be narrowed down with a WHERE filter?  Need to understand what you are doing.  Indices on NAMEID and COVERAGE help the JOIN.  But you are dumping all rows - so SQL Server is going to plow through it (using Cluster if available) and probably ignore indices because it "thinks" it must visit every row - so double-jumps from non-cluster to cluster is expensive.  If a Heap table - consider adding a Cluster

Comment: Ultimately, I'm wanting to be able to pull up all the information in my select statement by entering only a last name or nameid. So, I guess it would really only need to return a few (depending on how many coverage options the customer has). I'm using TOP 5 just to get a small return to use as an example.

Comment: okay good.  Try your query by adding a WHERE NAMEID = X - then optimize.  That is an important hint for SQL Server.  Right now you are trying to optimize for returning ALL rows - which isn't what you want.  Add more to the query - make it real-world - and see what that gives you.  SQL Server can start using indices based on better choices.  Do not use WITH hints !! (no really - it'll backfire later).  Good Queries first - Indices, Plan Guides, and Stat pages later if anything ...in that order.

Comment: Awesome! I've added it to accept a first or last name, then return the data. It took only a few seconds to do that. Thanks a ton!! Before I make myself look like an even bigger fool, is it possible to type a name into an Excel cell block, then pass that parameter to my query, then return the data back to Excel?

Comment: Yes.  But I don't know how  :-)  I think it requires VBA macro.  You can email me a Guinness.